# what's wrong with the query code?

Tags: 7

```
    $query = db_select('node', 'n')
                ->join('field_data_field_fenlei', 'c', 'n.nid = c.entity_id')
                ->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', 'c.field_fenlei_tid = th.tid')
                ->join('node_type', 'nt', 'n.type = nt.type')
                ->condition('n.type', 'product')
                ->condition( db_or()
                    ->condition('th.tid', arg(2), '=')
                    ->condition('th.parent', arg(2), '=') )
                ->fields('n', array('nid'))     // select nid field only so that node_load() will be called later
                ->extend('PagerDefault')        // this adds the pager
                ->limit(5);

$result = $query->execute();
```

product is the content type. field_fenlei is the category machine name . which is a select list, contains all the term.

i put the above code in the term template page file, the page shows unnormal(the page doesn't load the header part ....). there is something wrong with the query code?

is there a way to test whether the query code right or not?

Comment: What does _the page shows unorder_ mean? It's very hard to understand what you're actually asking here

Comment: the page doesn't load the header part ....

Comment: if i want to test whether the query code is right.how do i do? thank you

Comment: Do you mean how do you get the SQL string? You can cast the `$query` object to a string, e.g. `print (string) $query;`

Comment: when i echo (string) $query; the page is blank why?

Comment: I couldn't tell you I'm afraid, you'll need to look through your server logs to see what exceptions have arisen

Comment: if i delete ->join('field_data_field_fenlei', 'c', 'n.nid = c.entity_id')
                ->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', 'c.field_fenlei_tid = th.tid')
                ->join('node_type', 'nt', 'n.type = nt.type')
                ->condition('n.type', 'product')
                ->condition( db_or()
                    ->condition('th.tid', arg(2), '=')
                    ->condition('th.parent', arg(2), '=') ) it can print the query

Comment: Check your error logs, you'll almost definitely have a `PDOException` in there. It should tell you exactly what the problem is

Comment: i don't know how to check the error logs. could you test the query code in your environment. thank you.you create a content type product then created a filed_fenlei, then create some terms under it.then put the query code in the term template page

Comment: No I've got other things to do, sorry. Check the answer, other than that I can't help any further here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohhh I've just realised why you're getting an error...`join()` isn't chainable, it returns the created alias to the joined table.

Try this instead:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->condition('n.type', 'product')
  ->condition( db_or()
    ->condition('th.tid', arg(2), '=')
    ->condition('th.parent', arg(2), '=') )
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))     
  ->extend('PagerDefault')        // this adds the pager
  ->limit(5);

$query->join('field_data_field_fenlei', 'c', 'n.nid = c.entity_id');
$query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', 'c.field_fenlei_tid = th.tid');
$query->join('node_type', 'nt', 'n.type = nt.type');

$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: this is the [queryString] => SELECT n.nid AS nid
FROM 
node n
INNER JOIN field_data_field_fenlei c ON n.nid = c.entity_id
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy th ON c.field_fenlei_tid = th.tid
INNER JOIN node_type nt ON n.type = nt.type
WHERE  (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND( (th.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) OR (th.parent = :db_condition_placeholder_2) )
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
)

Comment: there is still no any output.

Comment: why the where condition can't get the value?

Comment: [Apache error logs docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#errorlog). Like I said, I can't help any further. It sounds like you might want to hire a consultant, you don't seem to understand the technologies you're using here

Comment: @123 I would suggest accepting this answer, as it exactly says why the code you shown here doesn't work. Between you and your colleague, you asked 8 questions to solve one issue. As you are not showing all the code used for the template file, it is not possible to understand why you don't get the expected result, considering we don't have important information, such as which theme it is set for the user testing the code, and for which theme that user edited the template file.